# how to configure a slack notification from gitlab for particular file change

Tags: gitlab, slack, serverless

I have a repository for serverless project in Gitlab. I want to trigger a slack notification when my **serverless.yml** file was changed against a particular branch. Please give some solutions against my query.

I tried to follow - [slack notification from gitlab](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/integrations/slack.html#triggers-available-for-slack-notifications) . But unable to understand that, for my exact requirement. If you have any answer, please help me.

Thanks
Aniket

Comment: Hi there! Stackoverflow isn't a free coding service, although I'm sure the community would love to help you out if you tell us what research you've done and specific problems you've encountered. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: edited, have a look into that. and if you have any solution, please share with me. thanks